# JqGrid's add form loads saved UserName and Password

Tags: jqgrid

I configured a JqGrid and it works perfectly,
but there is a little problem with saving UserName and Password for entered user in Google Chrome,

When an entered User confirm Google Chrome save his/her own password,while adding new User in JgGrid the saved UserName and Password will be loaded in adding form in their inputs.

colModel:

```
{ name: 'UserName', jsonmap: 'Username', width: 100, editable: true, editoptions: { defaultValue: '' }...
                },{ name: 'Password', width: 0, editable: true, hidden: true, edittype: 'password', editoptions: { defaultValue: ''}...
                }
```

Set defaultValue for Password and UserName to null string doesn't work:

```
editoptions: { defaultValue: '' }
```

if defaultValue is not null obviously it work,
also this solution doesn't work:

```
 beforeShowForm: function (form) {
                    $('#UserName', form).val('');
                    $('#Password', form).val('');}
```

Any solution is truly appreciated ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an easy solution just by setting "autocomplete" attribute to "off" the problem will be resolved as well,
code:

```
beforeShowForm: function (form) {
                    $('#UserName', form).attr('autocomplete', 'off');
                    $('#Password', form).attr('autocomplete', 'off');
                   }
```